# Templated iterator for a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, vector

I am creating a utility function to combine a byte array into a value based on the template type.

I currently have two overloaded functions which accept a pair of forward iterators and a pair of reverse iterators, in order to do take care of big and little endian.

Is it possible to have a templated vector iterator and reduce my two functions into one?

For example, this is what I want to do:

```
template <typename T, typename Iter>
inline T combine_bytes(std::vector<unsigned char>::Iter const &start,
                       std::vector<unsigned char>::Iter const &end,
                       bool bigendian)
{
    T ret;
    std::copy(start, end, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&ret));

    return ret;
}
```

The compilation error I get is:

```
Failed to specialize function template 'T Utils::combine_bytes(const Iter &, const Iter &)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `static_assert` to ensure the type referenced by your iterator is `unsigned char`.  Then you don't have to worry about what type of container is being iterated over:

```
template <typename T, typename Iter>
inline T combine_bytes(Iter start, Iter end)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(*start)>, unsigned char>::value,
                  "Must use unsigned char");
    T ret;
    std::copy(start, end, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&ret));

    return ret;
}
```

While you're at it, you may want to add some runtime checking to make sure `std::distance(begin, end) == sizeof(T)` if you didn't just leave that out to keep the example short.

Comment: Does this approach use SFINAE? I am guessing no.

Comment: To get this to compile, I need to change the type to check against in the `static_assert` to `unsigned char &`. So it looks like this now:     `static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(*start), unsigned char &>::value,
                  "Must use unsigned char");`

Comment: @ctzdev Oops.  You can use `std::decay_t<decltype(*start)>` instead of just `decltype(*start)`.  That's technically a bit more correct than using `unsigned char&` since it will accept read-only iterators, but the difference is minor.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that, using SFINAE, you can write something as follows

```
template <typename T, typename Iter>
inline typename std::enable_if<
      std::is_same<Iter, std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator>{}
   || std::is_same<Iter, std::vector<unsigned char>::reverse_iterator>{},
   T >::type combine_bytes (Iter const & start,
                            Iter const & end,
                            bool bigendian)
{
    T ret;
    std::copy(start, end, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&ret));

    return ret;
}
```

that is: define the function for a generic template type `Iter` and enable it only if `Iter` is `std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator` or `std::vector<unsigned char>::reverse_iterator`

Comment: Are there any added benefits to this approach compared to Miles Budnek's approach?

Comment: @ctzdev - not necessarily; depends from yours requirements; if you prepare different functions for different types, I suppose is better use `std::enable_if` to avoid ambiguity or to avoid that the wrong version is preferred. If you have a simple case with only a function that has to be used only with a set of types, I suppose that a `static_assert()` is a simpler, and good enough, solution.